# Import file with JSFL

Tags: image, flash, import, jsfl

I am current using this script to import a file into my library using jsfl

```
var dom = fl.getDocumentDOM(); 
uri = "file:///c|/sound.png"
dom.importFile(uri,true);
```

Is it possible to replace the local address file:///c|/sound.png with an web adress eg. http://website.com/folder/sound.png ?